# TFS build service is not restarting

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

TFS build agents are in "unknown" state. Their state in "enabled" but their status is "offline". When I am restarting the TFS build service, it is saying 
[image]

when I am queuing a build on any of the build agent of that build controller, it says "waiting for agent".  How it can be back to "available" status.

Answer (score 0):

This might simply be a permissions issue:

Granting the group **`[Default Collection]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts`** membership
of

**`[Default Collection]\Project Collection Build Administrators`**

Also give a try with install the latest SP of TFS2010, and reboot TFS server.